# Setting Attribute of a file in network

Tags: c#, networking, file-permissions

I want to set attribute of a file in network to ReadOnly.

```
File.SetAttributes(@"\\data\ntshare\tmp\Trades_LastFileUploaded.csv", FileAttributes.ReadOnly);
```

It goes fine, but after this when i check my file over network it still appears to be !readOnly.
Also, when i try to manually (using file properties) set the ReadOnly flag. It goes fine, but when i open the properties it again becomes !readonly.

Could it be some network permission rule?
I am able to create and delete files from the same directory, why would it restrict me to set file properties?

Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, sounds like your user account does not have Write Attributes right to the file in question.